# Accents in compound words and words with enclitics

Tags: pronunciation, prefix, stress

I've been learning Latin on my own for the last 4 months or so using Wheelock and Moreland & Fleischer. I've not been able to find answers to the following accentuation questions in either of those texts. Hoping someone here can help

1. Where do you put the accent in a compound Latin word like "circumeo". Taken separately, the accent is on the first syllable for both circum and eo. The accentuation rules that I've learned suggest that the accent on circumeo should be on the second syllable (cu) — i.e. the antepenult. But, as an English speaker, that sounds funny.
2. How about when there's an enclitic? Where's the accent in animusque? Taken separately, the accent in animus is on the first syllable, the antepenult (a). The accentuation rules suggest that the accent in animusque should be on the penult (mus). Is that right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Closely related: [Are there exceptions to the Latin stress rules?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/600)

Comment: @sumelic That is indeed closely related, but it would be great if someone could write up an answer specifically for this question.

Comment: @DaddyWhale Since there are no answers yet, it might make sense to split your question and ask the other part separately. That way they would be easier to find and answer. How does this sound?

Comment: @Joonaslimavirta Sounds good.  I'm new to stackexchange.  I'll try breaking it up.

Comment: @sumelic.  Thanks for the advice on enclitics.  I've come to this same conclusion from what I've learned from other websites.

Answer (score 1):

Good question!

For the first part, it depends on the prefix, and how firmly attached that prefix is. Most common prefixes (*ex-*, *ad-*, *in-*, etc) attach very firmly to the stem and become part of the word: *éxit*, *ádsum*, *íngens*. You'll notice that these prefixes also change their form when necessary to fit into the sounds around them: *i**m**par*, *a**f**ficiō*.

*Circum*, on the other hand, never really attached in the same way. Romans often wrote it separately from the verb—*circum eō* instead of *circumeō*—and in some cases even stuck extra words in the middle! It also doesn't assimilate to the words it's stuck to: *circu**m**torqueō* is written consistently with an *m* instead of an *n*. So whether you write the parts as one word or two, there's evidence that you should accent them separately, as *círcum-éō*.

For the second part, the rule I learned ([which this answer cites to Allen and Greenough](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/601/406)) is that *the accent always goes right before the enclitic*. This happens when the stressed syllable is heavy, but *also* when it's light: *animús-que*, but also *caderé-ve*, etc. However, C. M. Weimer says this isn't universally accepted, and it's difficult to find solid proof at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The question about enclitics has been addressed elsewhere on this site; e.g. in [C. M. Weimer's answer to *Are there exceptions to the Latin stress rules?*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/601/9) and [my answer to *Were enclitics considered part of a word for stress purposes?*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/8981/9). (My answer to that second question is not very good; it would be nice if somebody could post a better one.) The correct general rule is debated, but in the specific case of words like *animusque,* there is agreement that the accent would fall on the heavy syllable immediately preceding *-que.*

The question about *circumeo* is different, but hard to answer. As mentioned in the answers to the linked posts above, there were exceptions to the Latin stress rule. Even in cases where the rule applies regularly, it can be difficult to determine the relevant boundaries for the application of the rule. C. M. Weimer's answer explains that even though forms like *benefacit* may be found written without spacing, the forms of *benefacio* are thought to have been stressed the same way as the verb *facio;* i.e. *beneˈfacit* and not **beˈnefacit.*

#### The issue of the pronunciation of *-um*

Here is some background information about another issue of Latin pronunciation that is relevant. When a word ending in *-um* comes before a word that starts with a vowel, the two-word sequence typically scans as if the *-um* were absent. This, along with some statements from Latin grammarians about the pronunciation of word-final M, has been interpreted as implying that word-final *-um* (or any other word-final vowel + m sequence) was pronounced not as a vowel followed by the consonant sound [m], but as a nasal vowel sound, which changed according to its environment in the following ways:

- before another vowel, a nasal vowel was usually elided. I say "usually" because it seems likely that hiatus was possible. As far as I can gather, in the case of hiatus, the first vowel would apparently scan as short. There is more information about elision in general in the following article: "[Elision and Hiatus in Latin Prose and Verse](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3287750?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)", by E. H. Sturtevant. I will look to see if there are examples of the word *circum* having the *um* elided in verse.
- before a plosive or nasal consonant, a nasal vowel was converted into a sequence of short vowel + a nasal consonant homorganic to the following consonant. E.g. *circ[uŋ] capita.*
- before other kinds of consonants, a nasal vowel would remain as a nasal vowel, which scanned as a long vowel. E.g. *circ[ũː] familias.*

#### *Circumeo* is an unusual *circum-* word

Andras Cser's "[Aspects of the Phonology and
Morphology of Classical Latin](http://real-d.mtak.hu/896/7/dc_1106_15_doktori_mu.pdf)" (2016) has a section on *circum-* (8.2.3.4.). Like Draconis, Cser notes that the spelling of *circum-* does not change before consonants.

But in *circumeo,* *circum-* is not followed by a consonant. In fact, in this word we can find the alternative form *circu-,* as in *circuit.* Cser says the following about the distribution of *circum-* and *circu-* in this word:

> With *ire* there is an interesting imbalance between *circum-* vs. *circu-*: if the stem form begins with [i], the form *circu-* is more frequent, when the stem form begins with [e], *circum-* is more usual (thus *circu-it* but *circum-eunt* rather than vice versa, though all variants occur).

Cser says that, although in most words *circum-* behaves more like the first element of a compound than like a prefix,

> *circuire* suggests prefixation rather than a compound boundary, and hence deletion of the placeless nasal just as is *coire*

(p. 157)

Cser also says that it is uncertain whether the forms spelled with <um> followed by a vowel, such as *circumeunt,* were pronounced with a consonant sound [m]. Cser doesn't seem to discuss stress, but I assume that that would likewise be somewhat uncertain.

#### Other *Circum-* words

Here are the details of what Cser says about other *circum-* words:

> Words prefixed with *circum-* are much more like compounds than words
> prefixed with *con-*: their meanings are usually more compositional, stem vowel
> weakening is hardly ever found in them (*circumcidere* ‘cut around’ and
> *circumcludere* ‘enclose’ were probably lexicalised early), and *circum-* can precede other prefixes (e.g. *circumobruere* ‘wrap around’ with *ob-*). In this respect *circum* resembles the other disyllables *retro* ‘backwards’, *intro* ‘in’, *extra* ‘out’, which formed compounds (if at all), but did not function as prefixes in the strict sense of the word.

(p. 157)

As I said, Cser doesn't address the topic of stress in this section, so I'm not sure whether compound words starting with *circum-* would be expected to be stressed any differently from prefixed words.

#### Other links

Here is a link to a relevant discussion on the "Latin Discussion" forum: [Composite words](http://latindiscussion.com/forum/latin/composite-words.11462/)